# Canvas images are fuzzy and not complete

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I tried every example that is on internet and NONE of them is working.
I tried to get a full image into a canvas, but it's zoomed in with really bad quality.

I tried rotate (standing pictures need to be laying) and I need the `dataurl` back.
Getting the `dataurl` was not the problem.
The problem is that it doesn't work.

```
<script>
        
function readFile(file, callback){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = callback
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    result = reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    console.log(result);
}

function snapitgetFile(){
    
    snapitloadshit();
}
    
function snapitloadshit(){
    $('#snapitUpload').on('change', function(e){
        var filesize = this.files[0].size;
        var filename = this.files[0].name;
        var extension = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('.')+1);
        var filePath = $(this).val();
        
    readFile(this.files[0], function(e) {
    //console.log(e.target.result);
    var canvas = document.getElementById("pic");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() { 
        var imgwidth = this.width;
        var imgheigt = this.height;
        $('#pic').css('height', imgheigt);
        $('#pic').css('width', imgwidth);   
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0,0);
            

    };
    image.src = e.target.result;
    
    
     });
    });
    
}
    </script>
```

demo: http://www.aeglobalresearch.com/demo/rotate.html

Try to select a picture and you see what I mean.
I googled and checked here, but all examples makes the picture look ugly or moves them to weird position.

I just want to get load the picture, rotate 90 degrees so a picture that is standing is laying.

Get the dataurl and than the rest of my script will do the rest.

Keeping all the exif, it just need to rotate 90 degrees right that's all.

What I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the rotation like this:

- make the canvas the same size as the image (as @Akaryatrh says),
- translate to the center of the image,
- rotate by 90 degrees (==90*Math.PI/180)
- draw the image offset by -img.width/2 and -img.height/2

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/NZZ3s/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var img=new Image();img.onload=start;img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/2014.png";


    function start(){
        canvas.width=img.width;
        canvas.height=img.height;
        ctx.translate(img.width/2,img.height/2);
        ctx.rotate(90 * Math.PI/180);
        ctx.drawImage(img,-img.width/2,-img.height/2);
    }


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This should be marked as best answer, your fiddle example better handles translation and rotation.

Answer (score 1):

Replace these lines :

```
$('#pic').css('height', imgheigt);
$('#pic').css('width', imgwidth)
```

With this :

```
canvas.height = imgheigt;
canvas.width = imgwidth;
```

Actually you were setting width and height css styles to your canvas, while you were supposed to modify element attributes.

[EDIT] Here's a full solution on jsfiddle with 90° rotation : http://jsfiddle.net/Akaryatrh/r6u9c/

Comment: thanks, a part is working but the strange thing is that my picture is somewhere down and only half visible

Comment: I'm currently building a complete solution with rotation, please wait less than 5mn for a fiddle link :)